# How to write OR expression correctly

Tags: python, logical-operators

I have a very simple program,
where it just check the user's 
input and ask eventually for a 
correct input.

```
player1 = input('Scissors (S), Rock (R), Paper (P) ?:')

while player1 is not 'S' or 'R' or 'P':
 player1 = input('Invalid Input, please choose correctly! /n Scissors (S), Rock (R), Paper (P) ?:')
```

If players1 is 'S' or 'R' or 'P' 
then it still asks for a correct input.
 I am not sure what I am missing. 
Excuse me if this might sound very trivial.

**Edit:**

writing it this way still does not recognize a correct input

```
   while player1 is not 'S' or player1 is not 'R' or player1 is not 'P':
   while player1 in {'S', 'R', 'P'}:
```

this way is just recognize 'S' as correct, if a type 'R' is still wrong

```
while player1 != 'S' and 'R' and 'P':
```

Correct:

```
while player1 != 'S' and player1 != 'R' and player1 != 'P':
```

Comment: Do not use `is` for equality checks, but `==`, and the logical connector should probably be `and` for your code to make some sense.

Comment: Your new issue is also a duplicate (can't find it now). TL;DR: Use `and`, not `or`.

Comment: Why and?   Just one input value should be entered and not all three of them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce is one of the dupes.

Comment: @xava Because you're doing an inequality check. Every input is either not `S` or not `R` (i.e. the condition is always true).

Comment: `x != 'S' or x != 'R'` is always true. You won't find a vaue for `x` for which it isn't

Comment: I used now != and the logical connector 'and' but now just the first value is correctly recognized

Comment: Now we're back to the original issue.

Comment: I have corrected it now, thank you for bearing with me